# How to add css class in a "delete" button of Symfony2 twig template?

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I am new at Symfony. My Symfony version is 2.5.7 I have generated a CRUD using "`generate:doctrine:crud`".

There is a delete button, in the view of each entry. I want to add css class inside button.

For this button, the generated code is -

```
{{ form(delete_form) }}
```

By inspection from the browser, I got -

```
<button type="submit" id="form_submit" name="form[submit]">Delete</button>
```

I have modified the generated twig code to -

```
{{ form_widget(delete_form, {'attr': {'class': 'btn btn-danger btn-lg'}}) }}
```

By inspection from the browser, I got -

```
<div id="form" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">
    <div>
        <button type="submit" id="form_submit" name="form[submit]">Delete</button>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="form__token" name="form[_token]" value="JrBKKEdf1F8hBDYIzu0TP9a4fauKvmlPMGg3rHwwA3w">
 </div>
```

So, the button is look like, now -

[image]

But I want it like -

[image]

So, my generated code should be look like -

```
<div>
    <button type="submit" id="form_submit" name="form[submit]" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Delete</button>
</div>
```

I have tried like, but it does not work - It is just showing normal delete button as, no class is included -

```
{{ form_widget(delete_form.submit, { 'label': 'Delete' }, { 'attr': {'class': 'btn btn-danger btn-lg', 'type': 'button'} }) }}
```

By the way, without the following twig code delete button does not delete the entry --

```
{{ form(delete_form) }}
```

How can I do it from with twig???

Comment: try to remove this line `{ 'label': 'Delete' },` form form_widhet

Comment: I tried, the look of the button has changed but now delete button does not delete the entry... :(

Answer (score 3):

I have solved the problem.. :) but not from twig.. from controller.. I have added the css class to `createDeleteForm()` method...

```
private function createDeleteForm($id)
    {
        return $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('book_delete', array('id' => $id)))
            ->setMethod('DELETE')
            ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Delete', 
                                            'attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-lg')))
            ->getForm()
        ;
    }
```

But i think, it is not the good practice.. :(

Comment: FYI, I always add classes and other attributes in the controller, not in twig.

Comment: Its better practice to all front-end related things keep in twig.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `{ 'label': 'Delete' }` and it should work. Here is an example:

```
{{ form_widget(delete_form.submit, { 'attr': {'class': 'btn btn-danger btn-lg', 'type': 'button'} }) }}
```

Comment: For me, this is the best answer.  The `.submit` made the difference.

Comment: This worked for me, i used `{{ form_widget(delete_form.submit, { 'attr': {'class': 'btn btn-danger'} }) }}`

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [Zed's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27165580/1069375) answer, but I also needed the label in another language, all without touching anything other than the TWIG template:

```
   {{ form_widget(delete_form.submit, {'label': 'Usuń', 'attr': {'class': 'btn btn-danger btn-lg', 'type': 'button', 'title': 'DELETE'} }) }}
```

Later on the same page, changed the default Update button:

```
{{ form_widget(edit_form.submit, {'label': 'Zapisz', 'attr': {'class': 'btn btn-save  btn-lg', 'type': 'button', 'title': 'UPDATE'} }) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

All the answers here works to add the class to the submit button. However, if one just uses this line with delete_form.submit the form won't work. The complete answer is:

```
{{ form_start(delete_form) }}
{{ form_widget(delete_form.submit, { 'attr': {'class': 'btn btn-danger', 'type': 'button'} }) }}
{{ form_end(delete_form) }}
```

As it is explained on the doc, form_widget doesn't render the form start and end tags:

```
{# renders all fields #}
{{ form_widget(form) }}

{# renders all fields *and* the form start and end tags #}
{{ form(form) }}
```